# I need to read many rows into a single SELECT row

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

I have a table one this:

```
Id    FieldId   Value 
----------------------
1  -   23    -    Jhon Smith    
2  -   24    -    jhon@gmail.com    
3  -   28    -    company name    
4  -   29    -    zipcode
```

I need a get all data from this table in one mysql query.

I need all this data in one row in query result.

Because a column: Value ->have a Name, Email, Company name and Zipcode.

This is because this table can create more fields for a form.

Comment: as in, SELECT * FROM MyTableName?

Comment: Question fixed. OP, can you tell us what you've tried? We do like to see some prior research here, before questions are asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct example. The structure of your table is wrong . Run these sql commands

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`zipcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`company_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



insert  into `test`(`id`,`name`,`email`,`zipcode`,`company_name`) values (1,'Jhon Smith','jhon@gmail.com','0123012','ABC Company');
```

And Now

```
SELECT * from test
```

Comment: Sorry, but how i get name, email, company name and zipcode in one row.

Comment: * means select all or you can do it like this too SELECT name,email,company,zipcode from table . All will be fetched if these column names exists in the table

Comment: Yes, but the table have this values in columns: Id - FieldId - Value. And column name is: Value and this hold a name, email or zipcode.

Comment: your question needs explanation you cant select name email from the above table if you have created a table put the structure then i will see what you neee

Comment: Yes, but the problem is: i not can change database structure, y use a joomla component tables, you table is good and easy but i not can change de table fields and names. I need a way to get all data in single row in mysql.